# Java and RestEasy Time Conversion Issue

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jackson, resteasy

I have two applications Application A and Application B.
A is calling B.Its a web service call
A is deployed in my local and its in EST
B is deployed in server which is in UK , BST
A is sending some date(java.util.Date) in DTO exposed by B
B is receiving improper date .
For e.g. If A is sending Sat June 5 8:30pm 1999 , B is receiving it as Sun June 6 1:30am 1999

How can this be resolved , so that if A is sending Sat June 5 1999 , B should receive it as same . (Time can be ignored)

Technologies used : Java , RestEasy.
Other pom dependencies

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.9.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: United Kingdom is 5 hours ahead of Eastern Time. So won't `receiving time - 5 hours` give you the required time?

Comment: hmm.. it may give ..

Answer (score 0):

They are both using the same point in time but they are both displaying it in their own time zone.

If you want to use a certain day without timezone you shouldn't use `java.util.Date`. Java 8 has a [LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for that. If you can't use Java 8 you'll find an equivalent in [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

If you use the Java 8 Date & Time API you should ad [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) to your dependencies.

Another solution would be using a simple `yyyy-mm-dd` formatted String.

Comment: My application is not using Java 8 ... and yes string can be used